# $\frac{a}{b}$ times a point on an elliptic curve

Tags: notation, elliptic-curves

Let $P$ be a point on an elliptic curve $E$.

I know the rule of doubling points - i.e $2P$, $3P$ and so on and **I was wondering** if there exists, what would be the meaning for $\frac{1}{2}P$, or $\frac{2}{3}P$ or in general $\frac{a}{b}P$ ?

I want to say that I am relatively new in the field of elliptic curves, so I hope this is not a very dumb question.

Comment: I presume $(a/b)P$ would be a solution to $[b]Q=[a]P$, but there may be up to $b^2$ such solutions....

Comment: Formally, one can think of $1/2P$ as extracting a square root of $P$, i.e. finding $Q$ such that $2Q=P$. In fact, just think that if the group of rational points of $E$ were written multiplicatively, $1/2P$ would be written as $P^{1/2}$.